# How can we use a condition inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

The following foreach query is inserting only values in ['options']['Colors'] and not those in ['options']['Color'] ???

**Updated Question:**

```
if (!is_array($value['options']['Colors'])) {
$value['options']['Colors'] = array($value['options']['Colors']);
}
if (!is_array($value['options']['Color'])) {
$value['options']['Color'] = array($value['options']['Color']);
}

if(isset($value['options']['Colors'])) {
$colorArr = $value['options']['Colors'];
} else if(isset($value['options']['Color'])) {
$colorArr = $value['options']['Color'];
}

foreach ($colorArr as $colors) {
$stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $PID, ':colors' => $colors));
}
```

Comment: off course not. `OR` is an operator that will look at the operands left and right of it, and result in a `true` or a `false`. You cannot `foreach` a `true` or a `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as this way... it does not make a sense. what exactly do you want to do ?

if you want check the existence of a value in array you could use in_array function like this:

```
if(in_array("someValue", $someArray)) {
    // Do something ...
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Okay holt, got it, but user3790186 changed her question and make my answer unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

We can not use OR in foreach loop. Instead we can use if statement to verify and then can go ahead like below:

```
if(isset($value['media']['options']['Colors'])) {
    $colorArr = $value['media']['options']['Colors'];
} else if(isset($value['media']['options']['colors'])) {
    $colorArr = $value['media']['options']['colors'];
}

foreach ($colorArr as $colors) {
    // You can use $colors now where you want
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question...the foreach loop is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on having the array such that either key may be used, I suggest you convert all to lower case before using them

```
foreach($value['media']['options'] as &$key => $value){
    if($key == 'Colors'){
        $key = 'colors';
    }
}
```

Then try using the array as before, but without the need for the OR statement checking for 'Colors'

Comment: $colorArr[ ] = $value['options']['Colors'];

Comment: The square brackets form an array. Your foreach is failing as $colorArr is currently not an array

Answer (score 0):

you could merge the arrays then loop, be careful of key conflicts though. can one option have both a "color" and a "Color" in which case it can get messy really fast, which one do you use, the first, the second, both, none?

```
    $colors = array_merge ($value['media']['options']['Colors'], $value['media']['options']['colors'] );

foreach($colors as $color ){

}
```